# Transpose data into table presentation

Tags: postgresql, transpose

I have the following data in PostgreSQL, that i want to transpose.

Column 2 - Represents the table ref, Column 3 is table cell ref, column 4 is the table row and column 5 is the value.

Desired Output would be

```
p_164 2017 2018
p_164  £ £
p_164 6,819,277 6,292,030
etc.
```

The number of rows (column 4) is variable

Source Data

```
1803147 p_164   42955214    0    2017
1803147 p_164   42955215    0    2016
1803147 p_164   42955216    1   £
1803147 p_164   42955217    1    £
1803147 p_164   42955218    2   6,819,277
1803147 p_164   42955219    2    6,292,030
1803147 p_164   42955220    3   (395,131)
1803147 p_164   42955221    3    (509,444)
1803147 p_164   42955222    4   6,424,146
1803147 p_164   42955223    4    5,782,586
1803147 p_164   42955224    5   (5,841,975)
1803147 p_164   42955225    5    (5,433,515)
1803147 p_164   42955226    6   582,171
1803147 p_164   42955227    6    349,071
1803147 p_164   42955228    7   -
1803147 p_164   42955229    7    6
1803147 p_164   42955230    8   (25,346)
1803147 p_164   42955231    8    (38,773)
1803147 p_164   42955232    9   556,825
1803147 p_164   42955233    9    . 310,304
1803147 p_164   42955234    10  40,962
1803147 p_164   42955235    10   49,704
1803147 p_164   42955236    11  597,787
1803147 p_164   42955237    11   360,008
1803147 p_164   42955238    12  597,787
1803147 p_164   42955239    13  597,787
1803147 p_164   42955240    13   360,008
1803147 p_164   42955241    14  (47,412)
1803147 p_164   42955242    14   (796)
1803147 p_164   42955243    15  645,199
1803147 p_164   42955244    15   360,804
1803147 p_164   42955245    16  597,787
1803147 p_164   42955246    16   360,008
1803147 p_164   42955247    17  (47,412)
1803147 p_164   42955248    17   (796)
1803147 p_164   42955249    18  645,199
1803147 p_164   42955250    18   360,804
1803147 p_164   42955251    19  597,787
1803147 p_164   42955252    19   360,008
1803148 p_249   42955253    0    
1803148 p_249   42955254    0   Note
1803148 p_249   42955255    0    
1803148 p_249   42955256    0   2017£
1803148 p_249   42955257    0    
1803148 p_249   42955258    0   2016£
1803148 p_249   42955259    1   FIXED ASSETS
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really transpose or cross-tab this unless you have a fixed (or at least finite) number of columns.

That said, I think you can accomplish exactly what you are trying to do by using PostgreSQL's arrays.

```
select col_2, array_agg (col_5) as col_5_values
from source_table
group by col_2, col_4
```

I think you'll find deconstructing the values very easy.  For example array[2] (`col_5_values[2]`) gives you the second element in the array.